# String with a list of number increment by 1 until it reach the specified number

Tags: vb.net

If i have a number e.g: 5, I would to have a string that have the number that start from zero and increment by 1 until it reaches the specified number. The output is something like this "0_1_2_3_4_5"

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: There are lots of way to do this, and I don't think there is one clear "best" way for something as specific as this. The simplest approach would be to obtain an enumerable of integers between 0 and your desired number, then use `String.Join` to join them.

Comment: Agreed. String.Join looks simple enough :) Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said earlier, there is no "best" way to do something basic like this. Use whatever approach you're comfortable with, as long as you're not doing anything horribly wrong.

Eg. one approach would be:

```
Dim myInt As Integer = 5
Dim result As String = String.Join("_", Enumerable.Range(0, myInt).Select(Function(x) x.ToString()))
```

Edit: Durr, I've been working with C# too long. Forgot how to declare variables in VB.Net. Fixed now.

Comment: This looks simplest enough :). Thanks a lot for sharing.